# Highcharts rangeSelector ytd

Tags: highcharts

I have a highstock chart with navigator synced with 4 highcharts graphs. I'd like to initially display YTD on all 5 charts, but the following gives me an xaxis error. Looks like it needs to be set after all charts are rendered. I've tried several places to no avail.

```
rangeSelector: {
    selected: 3
},
```

Any suggestions?

If it's not too much trouble,here's [the site I'm working on](http://www.capecodbay-monitor.org/). The code of 5 charts is too lengthy to display here. Click on any icon.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that setting `rangeSelector.selected: 3` triggers your `xAxis.events.setExtremes` function, which refers to your other charts that have not yet been initialized, and it causes an error.

To fix this you could simply move your `chart1` constructor to the end, and do the other charts first.

In short:

```
$('#container2').highcharts({
    // ...
});
$('#container3').highcharts({
    // ...
});
$('#container4').highcharts({
    // ...
});
$('#container5').highcharts({
    // ...
});
$('#container1').highcharts('StockChart', {
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 3
    },
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            setExtremes: function (e) {
                var thisMin = e.min,
                    thisMax = e.max,
                    chart2 = $('#container2').highcharts();
                chart3 = $('#container3').highcharts();
                chart4 = $('#container4').highcharts();
                chart5 = $('#container5').highcharts();

                chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(thisMin, thisMax);
                chart3.xAxis[0].setExtremes(thisMin, thisMax);
                chart4.xAxis[0].setExtremes(thisMin, thisMax);
                chart5.xAxis[0].setExtremes(thisMin, thisMax);
            }
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

Comment: if you don't mind, for some reason I can't get the top highstock chart points to line up with the bottom 4 highchart graph points. I have no idea where to start looking. any chance you could point me to a reference?